# Sonarqube how to fix not construct the path from user-controlled data

Tags: sonarqube, java-11

Below piece of code is giving vulnerability issue in sonarqueb "Change this code to not construct the path from user-controlled data"

```
BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, false));
```

I tried below, but it is not working

```
if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, false));
}
```

And

```
if(Files.exists(file.toPath()) && Files.isExecutable(file.toPath())) {
BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, false));
}
```

What i am missing to validate before creating new buffered stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it with apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils like below

```
if(!FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename()).contains("exe")) {
//add allowed file extensions or not allowed file extensions like above        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never is too late to answer a question.
Analyzing your issue, I believe that you must validate and do a sanitization before - in the File upload and its name before every kind of manipulation itself.

There is a good guide available by [OWASP - Cheat Sheet Series](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/index.html) that explain everything that is considered dangerous in software development and also about [File Upload](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/File_Upload_Cheat_Sheet.html#filename-sanitization).